# FB Login Button and Comments Issues

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments, login-control

I am trying to incorporate a FB Login button and the Comments Social plugin w/ the javascript sdk. I have them each working independently but have issues when combining them. Are there any events I can subscribe to when a user logs in our out using the Comments plugin? FB.getLoginStatus, auth.authResponseChange, auth.login, etc. don't fire. I realize logging into comments isn't exactly authorizing my site, but I want to know when someone clicks "Not You?" link on comments and logs out since I'm using this auth for a voting app. I can get the comment.create and remove event ok.

Also, shouldn't the login button disappear when you're already logged into FB, or after clicking and authorizing the site? I'm showing/hiding based on FB.getLoginStatus response, but w/ the comments options it's proving difficult.